# onactivated is not called when application started

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, winjs

I'm programming an application Windows Phone using Cordova and WinJS. My problem is that the event WinJS.Application.onactivated is not getting called when I tested on the emulator Windows Phone. 
Did anyone have the same problem? 
Thanks

Comment: In a cordova app, it is recommanded to use deviceready event. is WinJS.Application.onactivated for specific purpose ?

Comment: As @t.ouvre said, place your code in deviceready function in the Cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows UWP platform, WinJS is loaded through `cordova.js` and unfortunately the `onactivated` event has been fired.
The solutions I used are by adding

1. ```
   <script src="WinJS/js/base.js"></script>
   ```

, or 2.

```
<script>
  if (!!window['Windows']) {
    Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onactivated = function (ev) {
    // store this ev object so that you can invoke it later
    }
  }
</script>`
```

in the `<head>` of your `index.html` to handle this `onactivated` event at the beginning of your App.

Please check [this help document of WebUIApplication Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication) to get more information.

One more thing needs to be mentioned. If you try to get a file from this `onactivated` event, you have better to get its RandomAccessStream from `storagefile.openAsync(...)` or blob from `MSApp.createFileFromStorageFile(storagfile)` in the handler of `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onactivated` directly because you may not have the ability or authority to open this StorageFile outside this event.